# POST using Curl with user ip

Tags: curl

I'm making a script that post on a website using curl and i was wondering if i can make the post using user's IP (actually i'm posting using server ip)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't spoof the IP address as CURL isn't the one providing it to the server you are connecting to, the TCP/IP network stack is. So there is no setting or switch to override, it is just a core mechanism of the network communication.